# open("../data/../data/ in terminal ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a code which compiles. When I run the executable file in terminal the following error appears:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'chrono::ChException'
what():  Cannot open stream
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I then run:

```
strace -e trace=open ./myexe
```

And I see that the program fails at:

```
open("../data/../data/_template_POV.pov", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I have a file called "_template_POV.pov" but I don't know where to paste the file since do not know what "../data/../data/" means.

Can anyone help me?

Regards, 
Anders

Comment: `..` is the parent directory. So `../data` means `data` in the parent directory, etc. `../data/../data/` can of course be shortened to `../data` since it just goes ‘up and down again’.

Comment: (…unless there's some link trickery involved.)

Comment: So I have made a folder named "data" in the directory where my executable file is and have copied "_template_POV.pov" into the folder. But the terminal gives the same error messages..

Comment: The location of the executable is (most likely) not important. Your *working directory* however, is. It is the base of the relative path. (Note though that the executable can change *its* working directory.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. How can I check the working directory?

Comment: It's where you ‘are’ when you run the executable. `pwd` will give you the whole path. Note that the `data` directory should be in *the parent directory* of the working directory.

Comment: So to see if I understand you correctly: In the terminal I go to the directory of my executable. 'ls' shows that the data directory is in this directory as well and that the .pov file is in data as well. Is that correctly understood that my working directory is correct?

Comment: No. First of all; *the directory of the executable does not matter*! Only your working directory does. Second; the `data` directory should be in *the parent directory*. So if you're in `/foo/bar/baz` (cd `/foo/bar/baz`), then the file's path should be `/foo/bar/data/_template_POV.pov`.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping!! Now I finally understood what you where saying. I made the folder 'data' at the correct directory and i had to make one other folder as well, but now it is working. Once again, thank you very much and have a great weekend :)

Answer (score -1):

```
open("../data/../data/_template_POV.pov", O_RDONLY)
```

means that you should have your file in a directory ../data/ with a relative path of your executable. Could you check this ?

Comment: Yes, i have a folder names 'data' in the directory where my executable file is. In the 'data' folder is the file '_template_POV.pov'

Comment: no you should have a data directory in the parent directory of your exe (I said ../data/)

Comment: @Benjamin Not relative to the executable. Relative to the working directory.